# How to create a hyperlink from the data I get from a website with php

Tags: php

I'm in the middle of a stuggle here, I successfully return data from a website, but then the hyperlink from the site returns as text instead of a link. I wonder if there is any way that I can return it as a link. Also is it possible to display the information inside the hyperlink?

```
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">
    <?php
    $query = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=Select%20*%20From%20rss%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fworldoftanks.com%2Fnews%2Frss%2F%22&diagnostics=true';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($query);
    //var_dump($xml);
    echo '<h2>World of Tank News</h2>';
    //iterate over query result set
    $results = $xml->results;
    foreach ($results->item as $r){
        echo $r->title . "<br />";
        echo $r->link . "<br /><br />";
    }

    ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
echo $r->link . "<br /><br />";
```

do this:

```
echo "<a href=\"" . $r->link . "\">" . $r->link . "</a>";
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm :). now i need to figure out how to grap the data from the link into the site, i heard people saying using xpath is a good solution

Comment: Preferably `echo ... htmlentities($r->link)`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use

```
foreach ($results->item as $r){
    echo "<a href=\"" . $r->link . "\">" . $r->title . "</a><br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Thats look alot more user friendly

Answer (score 0):

For echoing HTML tags this way, I prefer to use [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf):

```php
printf(
  '<a href="%s">%s</a>'
    , htmlentities($r->link)
    , htmlentities($r->title)
);
```

`printf()` takes a string and `echo`s it after replacing specially-formatted tokens.  In the above example, there are two tokens in the string, both of which are represented as `%s`.

When `printf()` runs, it replaces each token with a corresponding parameter.  In the above example, the first `%s` is replaced by the result of `htmlentities($r->link)`, and the second `%s` is replaced by the result of `htmlentities($r->title)`.

[The manual page for `sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) goes into more detail about how the tokens work and has many more examples (`sprintf()` and `printf()` are identical except that `sprintf()` returns the formatted string, while `printf()` outputs it directly).

Comment: that pretty straight forward i will give this a try, thanks for the time try to explain it